# Netty - Delimiter for Xml Strings

Tags: java, xml, netty

I have implemented a TCP socket using JAVA and Netty where I am able to receive Strings from clients.
Now I also have reqirements to accept XML based strings and not quite sure which kind of delimiter I could use. At the moment I have the following implementation.

```
pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
```

With this the XML is read in line by line which is obvious. Now how can I tell Netty to read the whole XML string in? Am looking for some sort of xmlDelimiter.
Could someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a protocol issue that both sender and receiver has to agree upon. A real life example is that of NETCONF (used to configure network devices). NETCONF uses XML for both protocol operations and data encoding, and needed a mechanism for delimiting individual XML messages. The first version of the specification defined the string `]]>]]>` as the delimiter. A sequence of XML messages could looke like so:

```
<rpc message-id="1"> ... </rpc>
]]>]]>
<rpc message-id="2"> ... </rpc>
]]>]]>
```

It was later realized that this string may legally exist in XML attributes and comments, why a later version of the spec defines a totally different  framing mechanism based on length encoded chunks, much like the HTTP chunking mechanism.

If you have control of the clients and what they produce, a simple delimiter based approach like the original NETCONF solution should work fine.